# Regex to parse a simple odata query

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to create a regex to parse the following 2 strings

```
Country eq 'United States' and Value eq 1234.45M and CreatedOn eq '2013-06-05T06:04:23.2111146Z'
Value eq 1234.45M and Status eq 'Active' and CategoryID eq 1 and Country eq 'United States'
```

Basically these are OData query strings specified in **$filter**.
Note that this is for providing limited Odata support and hence the example strings have only **eq** and **and**.

This is what I have so far

```
(\w+)\seq\s\'{0,1}([0-9a-zA-Z,*=@#$&()-_+=!]*)\'{0,1}
```

This works for the most part except that when I have a space in a quoted string such as 
'United States' (note the space between United and States), it picks up only **'United**

I tried adding a \s to the range of characters to capture like so

```
(\w+)\seq\s\'{0,1}([0-9a-zA-Z,*\s=@#$&()-_+=!]*)\'{0,1}
```

but this throws the captured groups out of whack since the string itself can contain spaces to separate the name and value (Value eq 1234) <-- Note the spaces separating the **Value** and **eq**

Any guidance in fixing/recreating the regex above would be most appreciated.

UPDATE:I also need to support additional filter operations such as ('or','startswith','endswith','substringof').

Example:
**$filter** = *Country eq 'United States' and Value eq 1234.45M and substringof('Alfreds', CompanyName) eq true or startswith(CompanyName, 'Alfr') and endswith(CompanyName, 'Futterkiste')*

Comment: shouldn't it be: Country eq 'United States' and Value eq 1234.45M and CreatedOn eq '2013-06-05T06:04:23.2111146Z' **and** 
Value eq 1234.45M and Status eq 'Active' and CategoryID eq 1 and Country eq 'United States'

Comment: @NeverHopeless: I meant to imply two examples and hence the "missing" and :-)

Comment: so does my solution helps?

Comment: You indicated that you would check the various solutions and report back on which one was the most correct. It doesn't appear that you came back and marked your answer, I would like to know what you found since I'm tackling the same issue.

Comment: @Jim: Anurudh's solution is rock solid. I've been using it for the past 2 months and it's been working well. I would imagine you are  needing to parse OData queries in a REST service? If so what framework/technology are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match it with this regex

```
(\w+)\s*eq\s*'?([^']*)'?(?=\s*and|$)
```

Your code would be

```
var lst=Regex.Matches(input,regex)
                      .Cast<Match>()
                      .Select(x=>
                            new
                             {
                                 name=x.Groups[1].Value,
                                 value=x.Groups[2].Value
                             });
```

Now you can iterate over `lst`

```
foreach(var v in lst)
{
    v.name;
    v.value;
}
```

Comment: Nice. This seems to work pretty well. Thanks for your solution. I'll hit it with a bunch of tests and report back here

Comment: Thanks for the Regex it's been working really well so far. I also need to support some additional filter operations such as 'or','startswith','endswith','substringof'
Example:
$filter = Country eq 'United States' and Value eq 1234.45M and substringof('Alfreds', CompanyName) eq true or startswith(CompanyName, 'Alfr') and endswith(CompanyName, 'Futterkiste')

Would you be able to update your answer to include support for these?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this regex:

```
(\w+\seq\s'?[\w\s\.\:\-]+'?)(?= and |$)
```

Look for the example [here](http://rubular.com/r/hhzO6md3qe).

I am expecting a typo in your sample data:

> Country eq 'United States' and Value eq 1234.45M and CreatedOn eq
>   '2013-06-05T06:04:23.2111146Z' **and**  Value eq 1234.45M and Status
>   eq 'Active' and CategoryID eq 1 and Country eq 'United States'

Comment: It does help. Thanks for your solution. I am trying out all the regexes posted here and subjecting them to a battery of tests to ensure that corner cases are handled. I'll mark the winner as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Please try this regex:

```
(\w+)\seq\s\'?([^\']+)\'?
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this in two parts (Sorry for pseudocode, the question was at the beginning in general, and I'm not a .net guy (But I tested it in php)) :

```
input = "Country eq 'United States' and Value eq 1234.45M and CreatedOn eq '2013-06-05T06:04:23.2111146Z'"
splitted = split ("and", input);
```

And then do what I assumed was a replacement (because of capturing groups) :

```
foreach (splitted as s) {
    print (regex.replace ("#(\w+)\seq\s(.*)\s?$#", '$1 = $2', s));
}
```

In case php is easier to understand than my pseudocode, here is the code :

```
$string = "Country eq 'United States' and Value eq 1234.45M and CreatedOn eq '2013-06-05T06:04:23.2111146Z'";
$splitted = explode ('and', $string);

$regex = "#(\w+)\seq\s(.*)\s?$#";
foreach ($splitted as $s) {
    echo preg_replace ($regex, '$1 = $2<br />', $s);
}
```